# Is it possible to connect a Win RT app with PC via Bluetooth?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to find a sample that connect a Win RT app with other Bluetooth devices for example a PC. It is a basic thing but seems like it is not supported in WinRT.

In one [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/9db327e1-afe4-443b-8856-343492645083/) a Microsoft employee says

> .... Other than the call control sample, there is no Bluetooth stack
>   available for Store apps...

After reading other similar threads it seems to me that this is not possible at the moment. Am I right or is there any way to connect a Win RT app with some other device like a desktop app on PC via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

After reading many questions and articles (some links are below) on different forums I have reached to conclusion that communication between a Metro Style App and a PC is not possible via Bluetooth. One option is to go with is WiFi.

Some useful links which supports this conclusion are below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/6634240b-c042-4e76-a3b0-1f1103ea0ddf

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/0cb2a6c1-d1f1-4872-aa32-709acd90b94d

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/9db327e1-afe4-443b-8856-343492645083/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/172061f4-56ff-4fd2-987d-687d4703506d

Answer (score -1):

The WinRT 8.1 Bluetooth stack provides the requisite services for ad hoc Bluetooth communications with similarly capable devices.  More specifically, peer discovery and peer to peer communications is supported.